# Multipart upload using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am following below doc for multipart upload using boto3, but not able to perform the same.
can you walk me through concept and syntax for same?

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.create_multipart_upload

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.complete_multipart_upload

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site. Limit your question to a specific problem ,paste your code trials and share the error logs where you get blocked. Read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for better understanding.

Answer (score 5):

From [this](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html) document:

> **Using the Transfer Manager**
>
> **boto3** provides interfaces for managing various types of transfers with
> S3. Functionality includes:
>
> Automatically managing multipart and non-multipart uploads
>
> To ensure that multipart uploads only happen when absolutely
> necessary, you can use the **multipart_threshold** configuration
> parameter:

Use the following python code that uploads file to s3 and manages automatic multipart uploads.

```
import argparse
import boto3
import botocore
import os
import pandas as pd
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

def environment_set(access_key,secret_access_key):
    os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = access_key
    os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = secret_access_key

def s3_upload_file(args):     
    while True:
    try:
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        
        GB = 1024 ** 3
        
            # Ensure that multipart uploads only happen if the size of a transfer
            # is larger than S3's size limit for nonmultipart uploads, which is 5 GB.
            config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=5 * GB)

        s3.meta.client.upload_file(args.path, args.bucket, os.path.basename(args.path),Config=config)
        print "S3 Uploading successful"
        break
    except botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError:
        print "Network Error: Please Check your Internet Connection"
    except Exception, e:
        print e


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='UPLOAD A FILE TO PRE-EXISTING S3 BUCKET')
    parser.add_argument('path', metavar='PATH', type=str,
            help='Enter the Path to file to be uploaded to s3')
    parser.add_argument('bucket', metavar='BUCKET_NAME', type=str,
            help='Enter the name of the bucket to which file has to be uploaded')
    parser.add_argument('cred', metavar='CREDENTIALS', type=str,
            help='Enter the Path to credentials.csv, having AWS access key and secret access key')    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    df = pd.read_csv(args.cred, header=None)
    access_key = df.iloc[1,1]
    secret_access_key = df.iloc[1,2]
    environment_set(access_key,secret_access_key)
    s3_upload_file(args)
```